# Upper bound of the dimension of a vector space of functions with conditions on roots on a line

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $L$ be a vector space of functions from $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F$ such that if $f \in L$ and $f(x) = 0$ for more than $d$ points $x$ on a line in $\mathbb F^n$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all points on the line. Prove that the dimension of $L$ is at most $(d+1)^n$.

[Remark]

Equivalently, we can prove that if $\operatorname{dim}(L) > (d+1)^n$, then $\exists f \in L$ such that there are $d + 2$ points $\{x_i\}_{i \in [d+2]}$ on a line in $\mathbb F^n$ such that $f(x_i) = 0, \forall i \in [d+1]$ but $f(x_{d+2}) \neq 0$.

For each $f$, and $v, w \in \mathbb F^n$, $w \neq 0$, we let $\tilde{f}_{v,w}: \mathbb F \rightarrow \mathbb F$ be defined as $\tilde{f}_{v,w}(t) = f(v + t w)$. The condition says that if $f \in L$, then for each $v, w$, $\tilde{f}_{v,w}$ has $\leq d$ zeros or $\tilde{f}_{v,w} \equiv 0$.

[n=1]

When $n = 1$, assume $L$ has dimension $m > d + 1$, let $\{f_i\}_{i \in [m]}$ be a basis of $L$. Choose $d + 1$ distinct points (on a line which is the whole $\mathbb F$) $\{y_i\}_{i \in [d+1]} \subset \mathbb F$ and consider the system of $d+1$ linear equations $\sum_{i \in [m]} c_i f_i (y_j) = 0, j \in [d+1]$ on $m > d+1$ variables $(c_i)_{i \in [m]}$. Therefore, there must exist a nontrivial solution $(c_i)_{i \in [m]}$. However, because $L$ is a vector space, $g := \sum_{i \in [m]} c_i f_i \in L$ and now we have $g \not\equiv 0$ but $g$ vanishes on $d+1$ distinct points on a line, contradicting with the given condition.

I still have some problems generalizing the above idea to $n > 1$. I tried to use induction on $n$ but my current proof seems incorrect.

Assume that the proposition is true when $n \leq k$. When $n = k + 1$, for $f: \mathbb F^{k+1} \rightarrow \mathbb F$ and $v \in \mathbb F$, we let $f_v: \mathbb F^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb F$ be defined as $f_v(x_1, ..., x_k) = f(x_1, ..., x_k, v)$. Clearly, if $f \in L$, i.e., $f$ vanishes on more than $d$ points on a line implies that $f$ vanishes on the whole line, then $f_v$ has the same property, for all $v$. Therefore, by the induction hypothesis, the space $L_v := \{f_v: f \in L\}$ has dimension at most $(d+1)^k$, for each fixed $v$. On the other hand, for $f \in L$ and $X = (x_1, ..., x_k)$, we let $f_X: \mathbb F \rightarrow \mathbb F$ be defined as $f_X(v) = f(x_1, ..., x_k, v)$, which clearly satisfies the condition with $n = 1$. Therefore, the dimension of $L$ is at most $(d+1)^k \times (d+1) = (d+1)^{k+1}$.

[Self-solution]

We already prove the case when $n = 1$ above. Now we assume $n > 1$ and suppose the opposite, i.e., assume $L$ has dimension $m > (d+1)^n$, let $\{f_i\}_{i \in [m]}$ be a basis of $L$. Choose $d + 1$ distinct points $Y = \{y_i\}_{i \in [d+1]} \subset \mathbb F$ and consider the system of $(d+1)^n$ linear equations $\sum_{i \in [m]} c_i f_i (y_J) = 0, J = (j_k)_{k \in [n]} \in [d+1]^n$, where $y_J = (y_{j_k})_{k \in [n]}$. Note that the number of variable $m$ is strictly more than the number of linear equations $(d+1)^n$, therefore there must exist a nontrivial solution $(c_i)_{i \in [m]}$. On the other hand, because $L$ is a vector space and $\{f_i\}_{i \in [m]}$ is a basis, $g := \sum_{i \in [m]} c_i f_i \in L$ and $g \not\equiv 0$. Now we have $g(y_J) = 0$ for all $J \in [d+1]^n$. We fix any $n - 1$ variables, e.g., we fix $x_2, .., x_n$ with each $x_k \in Y$ and we have $g(y, x_2, ..., x_n) = 0$ for each $y \in Y$. Note that all points $(y, x_2, ..., x_n)_{y \in Y}$ are $d+1$ points on a line $\{(v, x_2, ..., x_n)\}_{v \in \mathbb F}$ in $\mathbb F^n$, thus we have $g(v, x_2, ..., x_n) = 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb F$. Note that $x_2, .., x_n$ can be arbitrarily chosen in $Y$, now we fix any $v_1 \in \mathbb F$ and keep the same $x_3, ..., x_n$ while let $x_2$ enumerate in $Y$, similarly, we can conclude that $g(v_1, v_2, x_3, ..., x_n) = 0$ for all $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb F$. We repeat the same process and finally we have $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb F^n$, i.e., $g \equiv 0$, which is a contradiction, completing the proof.

Comment: What are the hypothesis on $\mathbb F$? Can it be any field?

Comment: It's not specified in the problem, but I think we need $|\mathbb F| \geq d + 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $d+1$ points $y_1, \dots, y_{d+1} \in \mathbb F$ and for $i \in \{1, \dots, d+1\}$ $l_i(x)$ the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) equal to $1$ if $x=y_i$ and to zero for $x=y_j$ with $j \neq i$.

Denote for $(i_1, \dots, i_n) \in \{1, \dots, d+1\}^n=I$ the $n$ dimension polynomial defined by

$$L_{(i_1, \dots, i_n)}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = l_{i_1}(x_1) \dots l_{i_n}(x_n).$$

Prove by induction on $n$ that $\{L_{(i_1, \dots, i_n)} \mid (i_1, \dots, i_n) \in I\}$ spans $L$. This allows to conclude to the desired result.

Comment: Sorry. But it seems that the span of {Li,j∣1≤i≤d+1,1≤j≤n} should have dimension (d+1)n, not $(d+1)^n$. Maybe I misunderstand you. Apologize in advance.

Comment: @VezenBU Sorry for the typo.I updated my answer.

Comment: I think I got your idea, could you please kindly check my self-solution added in the question?